# Tyring to open a file with gksu gedit

Tags: 16.04, gedit, gksu

I'm trying to open the `/etc/group` file as root (to edit) but as soon as I type

```
gksu gedit /etc/group
```

It gives me

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:6959): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: @heynnena clearly says MIR in the error not wayland. For wayland set xhost no need to log out

Comment: So, what should I do? I'm kinda new into linux :/ Do the xorg thing?

Comment: Try avoiding running graphical apps with `sudo`, use something like `nano` for text editing (`sudo nano filename`).

Comment: I think OP do not use Wayland (it is 16.04 LTS, not 17.10 or 18.04 LTS). @IlanHerbach please post output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and try `sudo gedit /etc/group`. If you need to change users and groups you can use `users-admin` GUI  from `gnome-system-tools` package.

Comment: Use `sudo  -H gedit /etc/group`  If on 16.04 you could also install the `nautilus-admin` package. Then you'll find option in nautilus's context (r. click) menu